# Add text or draw lines on video

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, drawing

I'm searching for some library or tool for android for editing videos(e.g. drawing lines, adding text on some part of it). I tried to get frames of the video and add the text on some of them but it took a lot of time (8 seconds for video with 20 seconds length). So is there any way for editing video in a short time?

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, did you got any solution for this?